# Fluent interfaces and inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, fluent-interface

I'd like to build a base (abstract) class (let's call it `type::base`) with some common funcionality and a fluent interface, the problem I'm facing is the return type of all those methods

```
  class base {
    public:
       base();
       virtual ~base();

       base& with_foo();
       base& with_bar();
    protected:
       // whatever...
  };
```

Now I could make subtypes, e.g.:

```
  class my_type : public base {
    public:
      myType();        
      // more methods...
  };
```

The problem comes when using those subtypes like this:

```
 my_type build_my_type()
 {
    return my_type().with_foo().with_bar();
 }
```

This won't compile because we're returning base instead of my_type.

I know that I could just:

```
 my_type build_my_type()
 {
    my_type ret;
    ret.with_foo().with_bar();

    return ret;
 }
```

But I was thinking how can I implement it, and I've not found any valid ideas, some suggestion?

Comment: I've removed the namespace stuff because it has nothing (as far as I can see) to do with the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem of "losing the type" can be solved with templates - but it's rather complicated.

Eg.

```
class Pizza
{
  string topping;
public:
  virtual double price() const;
};

template <class T, class Base>
class FluentPizza : public Base
{
  T* withAnchovies() { ... some implementation ... };
};

class RectPizza : public FluentPizza<RectPizza, Pizza>
{
  double price() const { return length*width; :) }
};

class SquarePizza : public FluentPizza<SquarePizza, RectPizza>
{
   ... something else ...
};
```

You can then write

```
SquarePizza* p=(new SquarePizza)->withAnchovies();
```

The pattern is that instead of

```
class T : public B
```

you write

```
class T : public Fluent<T, B>
```

Another approach could be not to use fluent interface on the objects, but on pointers instead:

```
class Pizza { ... };
class RectPizza { ... };
class SquarePizza { ... whatever you might imagine ... };

template <class T>
class FluentPizzaPtr
{
  T* pizza;
public:
  FluentPizzaPtr withAnchovies() {
    pizza->addAnchovies(); // a nonfluent method
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Use like this:

```
FluentPizzaPtr<SquarePizza> squarePizzaFactory() { ... }

FluentPizzaPtr<SquarePizza> myPizza=squarePizzaFactory().withAnchovies();
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? It could be interesting.

Comment: cf. the edit. It may be interesting, I don't know if I'd personally use it, though...

Comment: So you actually switch to pointers. Then you can just use simple polymorphism, without CRTP, and return base*.

Comment: You can imagine references (if you don't want pointers) there. I just wouldn't make the methods always return a copy, but that's not the core issue. The main point of CRTP is to remove the decay to base (or base*, or base&), which is what I thought you'd like to avoid.

Comment: Now, the problem I see is that if in the fluent interface you return `return *this;` you are returning (.e.g.) `FluentPizza<RectPizza, Pizza>` instead of `RectPizza`

Comment: Also, a static_cast<RectPizza>( *this ) won't work because there is no constructor RectPizza for FluentInterface<RectPizza, Pizza>

Comment: If you're returning pointers or references, return a static_cast<RectPizza*>(this) or static_cast<RectPizza&>(*this) (the latter would work for copies too, if you don't mind changing the original too. If you want to return a copy and leave the original intact, do something like "T ret=*(T*)this; do_something_with_ret; return ret;"

Answer (score 4):

You should be returning references/pointers, and you should not need to keep the type information.

```
class base {
  public:
     base();
     virtual ~base();

     base &with_foo();
     base &with_bar();
  protected:
     // whatever...
};

class my_type : public base {
  public:
    my_type();        
    // more methods...
};

base *build_my_type()
{
   return &new my_type()->with_foo().with_bar();
}
```

You already have a virtual destructor.  Presumably you have other virtual functions.  Access everything through the base type and the virtual functions declared there.

Comment: The issue is that I do not want to lose the type.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would work like this:

```
return *static_cast<my_type*>(&my_type().with_foo().with_bar());
```

Using `static_cast` basically tells the compiler 'I know what I'm doing here'.

Answer (score -1):

In C++ you should be returing pointers or references rather than values. Also, you might want to explain what you mean by "fluent interfaces".

Comment: Sorry - as soon as I see the name "Martin" my bullsh*t detector goes off at full volume and I can read no more. Doesn't seem to matter if it's a forename or a surname, either.

Answer (score -2):

The way I'd do it in C#, and I believe it would work in C++ too is to provide a default implementation for `with_foo()` and `with_bar()`... Forgive my c#, but:

```
class base {
  virtual base with_foo()
  { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  virtual base with_bar();
  { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't fix the problem - the problem is a type mismatch, which is irrelevant of the question.